# What ODE book has good exercises?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

What book has good exercises for ODE? I would say I am just starting to study the subject rigorously, but I am pretty well-versed at math more broadly. I am reading the intro-level book by Coddington, but I find the exercises mechanical and not creative.

For me, examples of books with great exercises are Spivak's *Calculus*, Friedberg's *Linear Algebra*, Strang's *Linear Algebra*, Artin's *Algebra*, Courant's *Intro to Calculus and Analysis*, Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, the Stein/Shakarchi texts on analysis, Ahlfors' *Complex Analysis*.

Comment: Check the book by Gerald Teschl, it is available free of charge for download [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/). Some of the exercises are quite invoved though.

Comment: @Artem I have this book; in fact, it is the book for my current ODE course. I got the impression that the exercises/exposition are for someone that already has some experience and intuition with ODEs. Do you agree with this assessment? (The analysis there is not too difficult for me, but I feel like I'm missing an intuition about ODE.)

Comment: Yes, you are right, he covers *a lot* of additional stuff in exercises. For the intuition I would advise to take Arnold's ODE book (it has almost no exercises, but you can try to fill in missed details). Another wonderful book on ODE is Hirch and Smale (the first edition, not the one where Devaney also is an author), but I do not remeber about exercises there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love this one:

`Ordinary Differential Equations` by *Morris Tenenbaum, Harry Pollard*

Try it. It has a good taste :-)